# How to fix external HD?

Tags: hard-disk, luks, partition-table, superblock

I have an external HD which is divided into two partitions: an exFAT with 700GB and a LUKS partition with 300GB. I was copying from my computer to the luks partition but it got slow and stucked so I decided to remove the usb connection. Now the LUKS partition doesn't mount and it is filled with important files :( How can I fix this? Here are two outputs:

```
$ sudo parted -l

Model: ********** (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size   Type     File system  Sinalizador
 1      1049kB  300GB   300GB  primary
 2      300GB   1000GB  700GB  primary

$ sudo fsck /dev/sdb

fsck from util-linux 2.28.2
e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdb
```

Please help!

**Edit**

I followed *[this](https://linuxexpresso.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/repair-a-broken-ext4-superblock-in-ubuntu/)* tutorial and tried to restore to a superblock backup. Using this I find all the backups:

```
$ sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sdb

mke2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdb
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
Creating filesystem with 244189952 4k blocks and 61054976 inodes
Filesystem UUID: ***************************
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000, 214990848
```

I tried to restore to every single one of the block numbers listed but it always prompted me with the same error, for example:

```
$ sudo e2fsck -b 32768 /dev/sdb

e2fsck 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016)
e2fsck: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a dos partition table in /dev/sdb
```

Comment: When your system failed to mount the LUKS partition, what partition name did it mention in the error message? /dev/mapper/something?

Comment: did you try what the error message says (trying alternative super blocks, which also may be in other places, find out with "dumpe2fs /dev/sdb1| grep -i superblock")?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It's strange, now it apparently mounts and nautilus shows me the folders I have inside the partition, but when I go inside one of them it takes forever to show what's inside, and it doesn't show them.

Comment: @Jaleks I didn't try it, I don't know what it means to be honest...

Comment: @Jaleks Your command: dumpe2fs 1.43.3 (04-Sep-2016) \newline dumpe2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb1 \newline Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

Comment: sorry, was rubbish recommending a ext2 tool for an encrypted filesystem

Comment: I tried what the error message says and the same error message is shown. wtf?!

Answer (score 1):

### You're pointing the `fsck` command at the wrong device node.

Since your `/dev/sdb` is a partitioned disk, you should never run filesystem repair tools on the whole-disk device `/dev/sdb` - only on the actual partitions.

But since your `/dev/sdb2` is a LUKS encrypted partition, running `fsck` on `sdb2` is utterly futile - since the partition is encrypted, the contents of `sdb2` will look essentially indistinguishable from random noise, apart from the LUKS header. That's the encryption doing its job.

Instead, you must first unlock the encryption with:

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb2 sdb2_crypt
```

It should prompt for the encryption passphrase. If the command is successful, it will create another device node: `/dev/mapper/sdb2_crypt`. Using this device, and *only* this device, you will be able access the contents of the encrypted partition through the LUKS encryption/decryption "filter", making it look like a regular unencrypted device. When you shut down the system or use `cryptsetup luksClose` to lock the encryption, this device will vanish until the encryption is unlocked again.

This includes running a filesystem check:

```
fsck /dev/mapper/sdb2_crypt
```

Likewise, when mounting the encrypted partition, you must use the `/dev/mapper/sdb2_crypt` device and not the raw, encrypted `/dev/sdb2`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, check if your LUKS header is intact:

```
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sdb2
```

If you get an error, I'm sorry but unless you have a backup of your LUKS header, your important files cannot be recovered.

If you happen to have a backup of the LUKS header you can restore it:

```
cryptsetup luksHeaderRestore /dev/sdb2 --header-backup-file somefile
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to start on hardware layer.
Does /var/log/messages show any disk-related errors?
Cable or disk itself may be root cause of these issues, for example.
The problem is that if this is a hardware issue then it will very likely happen again even if the resulted disaster is recovered.